# Rewrite to append to query string

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I don't understand why I always have such a massive problem with rewrite rules, but I simply want to append to the query string if it exists and add a `?` if it does not.  I actually don't care if the URL is changed in the browser or not -- it just has to load the correct target page.

```
RewriteRule /cia16(.*)\?(.*) /cia$1?$2&CIA=16
RewriteRule /cia16(.*) /cia/$1?CIA=16
```

If I go to `/cia16/steps.php?page=1` it actually gets rewritten to `/cia/steps.php?CIA=16` -- that is it seems accept the query string part is not even considered part of the URL for the purposes of the rewrite.

What do I have to do to get the rewrite to work properly with an existing query string?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can't match against the query string within a `RewriteRule`, you need to match against the `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable in a `RewriteCond`. However, if you want to just append the query string, you can just use the `QSA` flag:

```
RewriteRule /cia16(.*) /cia/$1?CIA=16 [QSA]
```

The URI: `/cia16/steps.php?page=1` would get rewritten to `/cia/steps.php?CIA=16&page=1`. If for some reason, you need the `page=1` *before* the `CIA=16`, then you can do something like this:

```
RewriteRule /cia16(.*) /cia/$1?%{QUERY_STRING}&CIA=16
```

Comment: `[QSA]` does exactly what I need ... even though the syntax is frankly odd

Comment: This solution will return ?&CIA=16 if there is no query string to the initial url before redirection. Any tip to avoid that ?