# How to differentiate between a url with and without parameters using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I don't even know how I could title this question but here is the problem:

I use seo friendly urls on this project where there are services. Service links look like; `.com/services/service-title-6` and they get translated to; `.com/services.php?s=service-title-6`. On the other hand, pages don't have the .php extension at the end of their urls like: `.com/services` or `.com/about-us`.

The actual problem comes when I'm handling the switch between multiple display languages for this website. I just used a get parameter called `lang` and I can pass it to any page since I have a php file I call on every page to handle this along with other stuff. On my navigation bar, the language change button links are created dynamically so that the user doesn't have to leave the current page to change the website's language. So if you are viewing the about page, the link is: `.com/about-us?lang=en` to switch to English. This is generated in php like `$current_url . "?lang=en"`.

However, when I'm viewing a page with parameters such as a service, the link gets translated by .htaccess to something like: `.com/services.php?s=service-title-6?lang=en`. As you can tell, the 2nd question mark will get ignored as a parameter and not be passed. I would need to use an ampersand instead of the question mark. But when I'm just doing this on a regular page, I can't use ampersand by itself as it will be translated to: `.com/about-us.php&lang=en`.

Sorry for the long question but any help and ideas to handle this problem would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rewrite to append to query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15938598/rewrite-to-append-to-query-string)

Comment: So what is the actual question here? Seems it is not about .htaccess to begin with, but only how to properly create your URLs in the HTML code? Well then check if `$current_url` contains a question mark already - and depending on that, either append `?lang=en` or `&lang=en` then …?

Comment: @misorude first of all you can't create anything in the HTML code. As you can read in the question, URL that is generated in PHP does not have any question marks except for the language change buttons, simple URLs that are generated are handled by the htaccess. The first comment seems like it should work but I haven't been able to give it a try yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem by **appending** the next query string to my url. I wasn't aware of the `QSA` flag of mod_rewrite.

Here is my original rule for the services page:

`RewriteRule ^services/(.*?)/?$ services.php?s=$1 [L]`

I replaced it with:

`RewriteRule ^services/(.*?)/?$ services.php?s=$1&lang=$2 [L,QSA]`

I don't know if it's 100% reliable but it seems to work perfectly for what I need, even after doing a few tests.

(Thanks to [Joseph Sible-Reinstate Monica](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7509065/joseph-sible-reinstate-monica) for directing me to a helpful question.)